# JQuery defining a name of a variable outside of a function

Tags: jquery, dynamic

I have a generic function in which I am attempting to pass variable "names" that will be used in a for...each loop.  The code ultimately will populate a BootStrap IO Select component.

The function is calling a Web Service using AJAX but since so many of the methods are similar, I figured it was best practice to make it as generic as possible.

```
function setSelectData(selectControl, selectCaption, endPointName, codeField, descrField) {
    $(selectControl).empty();

    $(selectControl).append('<option selected="true" disabled>' + selectCaption + '</option>');
    $(selectControl).prop('selectedIndex', 0);


    // using jQuery & 'beforeSend' callback
    var username='****username****';
    var password='****password****';
    var error;
    var url = 'http://<myserver>/Hibrs/hibrs/lookup/' + endPointName;

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType:"json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: url,
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        },
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa(username+':'+password));
        },
        success: function(data) {
              $.each(data.list, function (key, entry) {
                $(selectControl).append('<option value=' + entry.codeField + '>' + entry.descrField + '</option>')
              })
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log('Error in processing! ' + textStatus + '||' + errorThrown);
            alert("Error: " + textStatus + '||' + errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

The call I am making to the function looks like this:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
   setSelectData(selectDrugType, 'Choose Drug Type', 'getDrugTypeValues', 'drugType', 'shortDescription')
});
```

The two variable names of interest are codeField and descrField.  These column names in the JSON return will differ depending on the code category. By passing the column names, I was hoping I could make this function fully generic.  But alas, it did not work stating that codeField and descrField are undefined.  I have Googled and searched StackOverflow to see if I can find a solution.  If I hardcode the JSON column names returned (i.e. entry.drugType and entry.shortDescription), the Select control is populated as expected.

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: Note that your username & password are going to be public if you send that script to anyone. Not matter how much you hide these values here. Hopefully you have some form of OAuth2 or similar capability to generate a temporary token for each user.

Comment: These actual scripts will never contain credentials.  This code is just POC that I am attempting to put together for the "real" application.  Thank you though for your concern.

Comment: Instead of `entry.codeField`, try `entry[codeField]`

Comment: Bingo!  Thank you, Justin.